# Possibility to not have to use curly brackets for itemize by using macro

Tags: macros, itemize

I have a macro for subitems:

```
\newcommand{\cvSubItem}[1]{%
  \begin{itemize}%
  \cvItem {#1}
  \end{itemize}%
}%
```

If I use it like:

```
\begin{itemize}
\cvItem First Item
\cvSubItem First Subitem
\end{itemize}
```

I get following output:

```
 - First Item 
   - F 
   irst Subitem
```

If I use curly brackets around "First Subitem":
`\cvSubItem {First Subitem}`
it works as expected. Is there a way to include the curly brackets in the macro , so that I don't have to set them while using the macro in the document?

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX reads `First subitem` as argument `F` followed by regular text `irst subitem`, as you note in your example.

So yes, you can change that. If you rewrite LaTeX from scratch, that is. This is ingrained in it's lowest levels.

Think a bit: How would LaTeX know just what goes "inside the braces" if you don't tell it? It makes perfect sense to continue your `First item` after you are done with the `First subitem`.

Comment: He/she could use the `\def\something#1\par{...}` trick, but it looks like a terrible idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But I dont know what you mean with "It makes perfect sense to continue your First item after you are done with the First subitem."  @vonbrand

Comment: @JairoA.delRio can you tell me more? Why does it looks like a terrible idea?

Comment: @RamonaK. Because you'll have to include an empty line after each item or an explicit `\par` to finish your argument.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.